# Link from woocommerce product not working

Tags: php

```
<div class='itemImage'>
 <a href='http://localhost/wordpress/produkt/product_name/'>
 <img src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/image-1.jpg' alt='product>
 </a>

   echo "<div class='itemImage'>
           <a href='$link'>
             <img src='$get_row->LINK_TO_IMAGE $get_row->SYMBOL-1.jpg' alt='$OriginalNamn'>
          </a>";
```

Above PHP Code create a html code. The html code look good for me but the image as link not working. If I put the cursor over the image that tell not that this is a link and I cannot visiting the link.

The link reads from woocommerce products database which this code

```
      

$sku = $get_row->SYMBOL;
$product_link = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $sku );
$link = get_permalink( $product_link);
```

What’s wrong?

Comment: Where are you writing echo in html? shouldn't it be within php tag like this: `<?php  echo "<div class='itemImage'>
           <a href='$link'>
             <img src='$get_row->LINK_TO_IMAGE $get_row->SYMBOL-1.jpg' alt='$OriginalNamn'>
          </a>"; ?>`

Comment: Hi all is in PHP tag

Comment: _“What’s wrong?”_ - you tell us! Did you check what $link contains, and is that what you expected? If it is not, did you check what $product_link contained, and was that what you expected? And if not, …

Comment: @misorude I can look it up. But as I understood the $product_link get the product_id by SKU and $link get the link to the product. And if you look on HTML code in <a href> this is the right and working link if I copy it and past in Webbrowser.

Comment: So the four lines of HTML code you have shown first, are the result of what the echo statement shown below actually creates? Apart from the missing closing quote after `alt='product`, that works fine … https://jsfiddle.net/8cjy6hen/

Comment: @misorude Hi I looked on line 4 and I think it was I which has removed it by changing the name of Product. If you look on PHP code you can see that there is all quotes. I will try out the code on jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi I get where the problem is. I have to use double “” quotes instead ‘ ‘ . But how can I du it in PHP code? If I use double quotes the I get error like (T_VARIABLE) or t_string error.